# How do I detect a certain mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a map and I want to make it so that when to defeat a zombie boss, a lever appears that sends you to the next level. Right now, I am trying:

```
/execute unless entity @e[type=zombie,distance=14] run /setblock -409 146 -208 lever
```

However, with this command, it activates the /setblock command even if the zombie is not defeated. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the command you listed triggers ***ONLY*** if the mob is exactly 14 blocks away.

In order to fix this, change the command by adding a .. in front of the 14. This means "select if the mob is at 14 blocks **or less**"

`/execute unless entity @e[type=zombie,distance=..14] run setblock -409 146 -208 lever`

As DisplayNameNotFound's answer says, it's always good practice to remove that second slash.

Comment: Thank you SO much! This worked, and now my boss fight works! Thank you!

Comment: @321Nathango you can mark the answer as “accepted” by clicking on the grey check mark. That way, users will know that the post is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few things you can try:

**Remove** the `/` at `/setblock`. The `/` may be causing minecraft to skip over the /execute and instead automatically do /setblock.

OR

Make sure the mob is actually in range. If the mob is outside a range of 14 blocks, the command will execute, giving an unwanted output.